# How to solve JSON Dictionary

Tags: ios, objective-c, json, uitableview

I fetched JSON and get in JSON Dictionary image, name, url. But i want get comment in JSON dictionary and reload in `tableView`. I tried but get null value. so please help how to get comment and reload in tableview. please below check my code and tell where I am wrong. Thank you.

**MY JSON**

```
(
    {
    image = "http://sixthsenseit.com/school/project/uploades/160223032210.png";
    likes = 3;
    name = "RADHIKA SAXENA";
    url = "http://sixthsenseit.com/school/my-school/uploads/photo_1448551101.jpg";
},
    {
    comment =         (
                    {
            comment = q;
            name = "";
        },
                    {
            comment = f;
            name = "";
        },
                    {
            comment = ffgggggggg;
            name = "";
        },
                    {
            comment = vcvg;
            name = "";
        },
                    {
            comment = ggg;
            name = "";
        },
                    {
            comment = aad;
            name = "";
        },
                    {
            comment = anku;
            name = "";
        },
                    {
            comment = gffgffg;
            name = "";
        },
                    {
            comment = fggg;
            name = "";
        },
                    {
            comment = vgghj;
            name = "";
        },
                    {
            comment = ffgfh;
            name = testing;
        },
                    {
            comment = bnVib;
            name = "HARSHALI SHARMA";
        }
    );
}
)
```

**GET RESPONSE IN ViewDidLoad**

```
 NSMutableURLRequest *request = [[NSMutableURLRequest alloc] initWithURL:[NSURL URLWithString:@"http://sixthsenseit.com/school/project/ios/image_data.php"]];


//create the Method "GET" or "POST"
[request setHTTPMethod:@"POST"];

//Pass The String to server(YOU SHOULD GIVE YOUR PARAMETERS INSTEAD OF MY PARAMETERS)
NSString *userUpdate =[NSString stringWithFormat:@"pid=%@&uid=%@&",@"29",@"1000710017", nil];



//Check The Value what we passed
// NSLog(@"the data Details is =%@", userUpdate);

//Convert the String to Data
NSData *data1 = [userUpdate dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];

//Apply the data to the body
[request setHTTPBody:data1];

 //Create the response and Error
NSError *err;
NSURLResponse *response;

NSData *responseData = [NSURLConnection sendSynchronousRequest:request returningResponse:&response error:&err];


NSArray *json = [NSJSONSerialization JSONObjectWithData:responseData
                                                     options:kNilOptions
                                                       error:&err];

  NSLog(@"results == %@",json);

 _name.text = [[json objectAtIndex:0]objectForKey:@"name"];

 image = [[json objectAtIndex:0]objectForKey:@"url"];
 NSURL *url = [NSURL URLWithString:image];
 NSData *imageData = [NSData dataWithContentsOfURL:url];
 _image.image = [UIImage imageWithData:imageData];

url = [[json objectAtIndex:0]objectForKey:@"image"];
NSURL *urls = [NSURL URLWithString:url];
NSData *imageDatas = [NSData dataWithContentsOfURL:urls];
_url.image = [UIImage imageWithData:imageDatas];

comment_ary = [json valueForKey:@"comment"];
```

**TableView Methods**

```
- (NSInteger)numberOfSectionsInTableView:(UITableView *)tableView
{
return 1;
}
- (NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section
{
return [comment_ary count];
}


- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
//NSLog(@"tableview cell");
CommentCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:@"htrcell"];
if (cell==nil)
{
    NSArray *nib = [[NSBundle mainBundle] loadNibNamed:@"Cell" owner:self options:nil];
    cell = [nib objectAtIndex:0];
}
NSDictionary *getValues =  comment_ary [indexPath.row];
cell.name.text=[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@",getValues [@"name"]];
cell.comment.text=[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@",getValues[@"comment"]];
return  cell;
}
```

Comment: Json returned is an array which has 2 objects

Comment: you must get the second object of the array and then save it as dictionary.

Comment: and after that get the value for "comment"

Comment: @AbdulRehmanWarraich how to resolve and get second object and reload comment and name in tableview

Comment: @BhadreshKathiriya OK i updated my code please wait

Comment: @BhadreshKathiriya please check my updated code

Comment: @ankurkumawat Have you check my answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to get comment from second object of `NSArray` json and after that reload your `TableView`.

```
self.comment_ary = [[json objectAtIndex:1] objectForKey:@"comment"];
[self.tableView reloadData];
```

Answer (score 2):

You are not requesting for right key at right place 
You should do this

```
comment_ary = [[json objectAtIndex:1]objectForKey:@"comment"];
```

not this

```
comment_ary = [json valueForKey:@"comment"];
```

Answer (score 0):

plz use

```
comment_ary = [[[json objectAtIndex:1]objectForKey:@"comment"] objectAtIndex:0];
```

hope its help

Comment: Please explain why it should help.

Comment: @rptwsthi plz read the question . my anser work same as these two above answers.

Comment: If your answer is same as other then please upvote other answer instead of adding new,

Comment: @rptwsthi i did the up vote for both answers. check the timing of answers they answer same time as mine. plz clear all things before comment